# Degrees in I graph

Tags: nodes, igraph, degrees

I am a Newbie in I-graph. I wish to know.

1. How to isolate nodes with a specific degree value?
2. How to know their node IDs
3. Can we draw a new graph with degrees above the given thresholds. Say nodes graph with nodes > n?

If there is any more tutorial/book with a more involved treatment of degree function, please let me know

Warm Regards

SHRINIVAS

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the vertex function `V()`, `degree()`, and base R functions like `which()` to get what you want. See below.

```
library(igraph)

set.seed(12345)
                                        # Generate a graph with a heterogeneous degree distribution
g <- sample_fitness_pl(
    no.of.nodes = 200,
    no.of.edges = 1000,
    exponent.out = 2
)
                                        # Plot to confirm
plot(g, vertex.label = "", vertex.size = 2)
                                        # Collect the degree sequence
k_i <- degree(g)
                                        # And the distinct observed degrees
k_bins <- sort(unique(k_i))
                                        # Plot the degree histogram
hist(k_i, breaks = 20)
                                        # Let's look at nodes with k_i = 10
n <- 10
                                        # We can use the base R function `which()` to return the node
                                        # IDs of those nodes with k_i = n
V(g)[which(k_i == n)]
## [1] 126 134 145 154
```

I think for (3) you want an induced subgraph with only those nodes with k_i > n. However, in the induced subgraph, those nodes will not necessarily have the same degree as in the original graph. If that isn't quite what you're looking for, see the manual [here](https://igraph.org/r/doc/subgraph.html) to see if there's a better option.

```
                                        # These are the nodes with k_1 >= n
plot(g, vertex.label = "", vertex.size = 2, vertex.color = ifelse(k_i > n, 2, 1))

h <- induced_subgraph(
    g,
    vids = V(g)[which(k_i >= n)]
)

plot(h, vertex.label = "", vertex.size = 3, vertex.color = 2)
```

For books, you might try [this one](https://www.worldcat.org/title/1157078035).

Comment: Thanks . Looks educative. Let me revert after little more application of mind and work out in my problems